# can not know windows phone 8 image format type

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Getting an image from media library on windows phone 8 using photo Chooser Task 
class it works fine but i need to know the format of that image. using image class will not work.and i need to access the photos stored in the emulator from the windows i get the root of the image but can not find it

```
 private void upload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
        photoChooserTask.Completed += PhotoChooserTaskCompleted;
        photoChooserTask.Show();

    }

    public void PhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if(e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        converttobase64(e);

    }
```

Comment: Have you got some code you're working with that doesn't work?  Hard to tell where/what is wrong.

Comment: that is the code i need to know the format of the image picked by the user

Comment: Would you not tell by the extension of `e.OriginalFileName`? in `PhotoChooserTaskCompleted`?

Comment: yes it return the full path of the image i know that thank you.

Comment: Image files are associated by extension.  You should be able to tell what type of image it is from the extension.  Also, have you tried he Bitmap class instead?